# Installing mongodb - mongodb-10gen or mongodb-org

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-server

I am trying to figure out what to install on my Ubuntu 12.04 server. I've read on multiple blogsites on how to install mongodb and it states there that you can install it through mongodb-10gen. On the other hand, the documentation on the mongodb site says that you should install it through mongodb-org. So which is which, and what is the difference between the two?
I've tried installing through mongodb-10gen and tried starting mongodb. The response said that it started but when I tried accessing mongodb it won't acess. I've tried checking the status and the response was it was not running.

Comment: The current and **recommended** method is documented on the MongoDB site: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/. The 10gen distributions are an old tag and should no longer be used for new installations.

Comment: @NeilLunn Okay, i'll try installing it as instructed by the documentation.

Comment: Fire following commands on your terminal. It works

sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev

sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10

echo deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen

sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen

mongod --repair

sudo service mongodb start

mongo

Comment: Why wasn't this question migrated?